# Understanding odeint results - disagreement with analytical solution

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I was playing around with odeint a few days back and thought some results were curious. So, I wanted to run something really straightforward to test my code (shown below).

If (dy/dt) = -x, integrating it should yield (-x^2)/2 + C. The plot that I got is defintely not showing that. It is clear I am doing something wrong but I cannot figure out what is missing. Can someone give me pointers?

Code follows -

```
import scipy.integrate as scint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def odefunc(y0, t):
    x = y0
    dxdt = -1*x
    return dxdt

plt.close('all')

t = np.arange(0, 5, 0.02)
y0 = 1

soln = scint.odeint(odefunc, y0, t)

fig1 = plt.figure(1, figsize = (9, 6))
plt.grid(color = 'grey', linestyle = ':', linewidth = 1)
plt.plot(t, soln, marker = 'd', linestyle = 'none', color = 'black')

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Event')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Here is the plot -

[Plot of the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBK3f.png)

I am fairly new to using python. This is not a homework question or anything. I am learning python for fun more than anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote "If (dy/dt) = -x, integrating it should yield (-x^2)/2 + C", but I think you mean "If (dy/dt) = -t, integrating it should yield (-t^2)/2 + C".  And that is not the equation that you implemented in the Python code.

Your implementation of `odefunc`,

```
def odefunc(y0, t):
    x = y0
    dxdt = -1*x
    return dxdt
```

corresponds to the differential equation dy/dt = -y.  The solution to
that equation is y(t) = y(0)*exp(-t).  *That* is the function that is plotted in your graph.

If you want to solve dy/dt = -t with `odeint`, then `odefunc` should be

```
def odefunc(y, t):
    return -t
```

Comment: "I think you mean "If (dy/dt) = -t, integrating it should yield (-t^2)/2 + C"." - This is what I meant to write yes.

And your answer makes perfect sense! Thanks a lot!